# BASH - Find all world writable files referenced in a set of files

Tags: bash, grep, rhel5

**Question:**  how can I find all world-writable files that are referenced in the startup scripts found in the /etc/init.d directory of a RHEL 5 server?

Constraints:

- BASH solutions only (this is part of a larger script)
- No additional tools/packages can be installed

Here's what I have so far.

```
worldWritable=$(find / -type f -perm -002)
startupScripts=$(ls -l /etc/init.d/* | tr '\011' ' ' | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 9,9 -d " ")
for file in $worldWritable
do
    for line in $startupScripts
    do
        grep -w "$file" $line | grep -v "^#" >> outFile
    done
done
```

This sort of works, but it takes a LONG time, and it includes a lot that's not correct (at least not what I'm looking for).  I just need "outFile" to contain a list of the world-writable files found to be referenced in any script in the /etc/init.d directory.

I don't mind completely abandoning this approach if anyone can offer a better solution.  I just need something faster and more reliable.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly but maybe something like `find / -type f -perm -002 -exec grep -l 'searchstring' {} \;` could reduce the amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major slowness certainly comes from the `find /`, scanning the entire filesystem. It will be faster to do the converse:

- Extract all the absolute paths from the init scripts

  - Using an appropriate regex, for example excluding matches where a # occurs earlier on the same line
- For each extracted potential path, check that:

  - The file actually exists
  - The file is world writable

The result should be significantly faster.

Comment: Yeah I had a similar thought, but I tested the `find /` and it only takes a little over 1 minute.  The big slowdown is the loop--it took just under an hour.  I'll try the reverse approach you suggest and see if I have any more luck.

Comment: Yep, that ended up being a much better approach.  Thanks for the feedback.